# react-native-tvos Reduce the delay between longLeft activation

Tags: react-native-tvos

I want to make my own progressbar and video navigation controlled from the remote control, but longright and longLeft have a large delay between activations, which is why fast navigation does not work.

```
  const myTVEventHandler = evt => {
     if (evt.eventType == 'longLeft'){
       video.current.seek(currentTime-30)
      }else if(evt.eventType == 'longRight'){
        video.current.seek(currentTime+30)
      }
    }
      useTVEventHandler(myTVEventHandler);
      const progress = currentTime/duration * 100
```

UseTVEventHandler did not find functionality such as longLeftDown or longLeftUp so that you can more finely control the state of keystrokes
Thanks.